# PHP 8.0.0 highlighting (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

In PhpStorm I am getting error highlighting after switching to the new PHP 8.0 syntax.

[image: Image showing the PhpStorm IDE with a yellow line under the line of code.]

My question is:

*How do I tell PhpStorm to recognise the new syntax of PHP 8.0.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Urmat Zhenaliev in the previous post, the EAP version is always up-to-date with the newest version releases of supported programming languages.

So for a developer that wants to program bleeding edge technology it is wise to think about EAP (early access program/releases) installations

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings (`Ctrl + Alt + S`) -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `PHP` and change `php language level` to your wished php version. You could also set path to cli interpreter if you want

[image: PhpStorm php language level settings]

Comment: As a side note, OP should probably also update their `composer.json` file to specify php 8 as well.

Comment: changing the PHP language level to 8.0 did not help to get the new highlight syntax correctly

Comment: @RenIar you should upgrade your phpstorm to EAP version then: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/10/phpstorm-2020-3-early-access-program-is-now-open/#set_language_level_from_status_bar

Comment: YES this answer is correct with the EAP it works flawlessly

Comment: For those who interested: PhpStorm **2020.3 final** is expected to be released very soon (later this week).

Comment: You can also see (and change) current PHP language level in status bar.